# Kohana ORM Aliasing and "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I have the following tables in the database:

- teams:

  - id
  - name
- matches:

  - id
  - team1_id
  - team2_id

I've defined the following [ORM](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm) models in my [Kohana](http://kohanaphp.com/) v2.3.4 application:

```
class Match_Model extends ORM {
  protected $belongs_to = array('team1_id' => 'team', 'team2_id' => 'team');
}

class Team_Model extends ORM {
  protected $has_many = array('matches');
}
```

The following code in a controller:

```
$match = ORM::factory('match',1);
echo $match->team1_id->name; /* <-- */
```

Is throwing the following error on the linke marked with `/* <--- */`:

*Trying to get property of non-object*

The framework is yielding the value of the foreign key instead of a reference to a Match_Model instance as it should (giving the has_many and belongs_to properties stated).

**Am I missing something?**

Note: Just in case, I've added the irregular plural `'match' => 'matches'` in application/config/inflector.php

Comment: Are you using KO2 or KO3? I don't know KO2 very well, but in KO3 those instance vars are prepended by an underscore (ie, _belongs_to, _has_many).

Comment: Thanks. I've added the kohana version to the question.-

Comment: have you tried a `print_r` on `$match` to see exactly what's in that variable?

Comment: I've tried Kohana::debug($match) and I can see that $match->team1_id holds just a numeric value (the value stored in the database in that column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!** The Kohana community gave me the [answer](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=5671):

The correct value for the $belongs_to property is:

```
class Match_Model extends ORM {
  protected $belongs_to = array('team1' => 'team', 'team2' => 'team');
}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm/advanced) states it:

> ```
> class Blog_Post_Model extends ORM { 
>     protected $belongs_to = array('author' => 'user', 'editor' => 'user'); 
> }
> ```
>
> The blog_posts database table would
>   have 2 columns now,
>   blog_posts.author_id  and
>   blog_posts.editor_id, and both would
>   have values that exist in users.id.

It seems that I've missed that line, :)